# Hotkey problem with (AltGr) (<^>!) (LCtrl & RAlt)?

Tags: autohotkey

- I want while holding down "AltGr " then(and) "SC033" it stills doing undo, undo, undo ... until release "SC033".
- as for <^>!p the same thing for <^>!SC033 but it stills doing redo, redo, redo ... until release "p".
- as for LCtrl & RAlt Up:: (The text shown in the MsgBox)

I've tried this but it doesn't what I want :

```
LCtrl & RAlt Up:: MsgBox, Only AltGr has been pressed down and released.
<^>!SC033::Send ^z
<^>!p::Send ^y
```

The problem with this is, when pressing and releasing <^>!p or <^>!SC033 the MsgBox appears. (it neither does undo nor redo).

I've also tried this, But it doesn't exactly waht I want :

```
LCtrl & RAlt Up::
    If (A_PriorKey = "RAlt"){
        MsgBox, Only AltGr has been pressed down and released.
    }
    If (A_PriorKey = "SC033"){
        Send ^z
    }
    If (A_PriorKey = "p"){
        Send ^z
    }
Return
```

Note : SC033 is the character ;

- I use AutoHotkey V1.1.37.01
  Any help to do so please!

Answer (score 0):

By executing `MsgBox` you are setting the focus on the MsgBox window.
In order to send the keystrokes to the desired window, either avoid using `MsgBox` at all or use `WinActivate()` before executing `Send` to focus the desired window and eventually send the keystrokes to the correct window.

You can also use `ControlSend` if you want to leave the focus on the MsgBox but still send the keystrokes to the desired window.